# Most Visualization Tools are Missing from Orange.Canvas (2015/06/15 source)

Tags: orange

My orange-canvas is installed on Mint14 under Anaconda python2 environment. Tools appears in "Visualize" section are: Attribute Statistics, Mosaic Display, Sieve Diagram and Venn Diagram. The X-Y Scatter plot module, in particular, is the one I will need.

The source is acquired from github, compiled by the instruction:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

The following error appears multiple times when compiling source:

```
warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
```

Most files are installed to:

```
/usr/local/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Orange/
```

Installed Anaconda packages:

```
# packages in environment at /usr/local/conda:
#
_license                  1.1                      py27_0  
abstract-rendering        0.5.1                np19py27_0  
anaconda                  2.2.0                np19py27_0  
argcomplete               0.8.4                    py27_0  
astropy                   1.0.1                np19py27_0  
atom                      0.3.9                    py27_0  
backports.ssl-match-hostname 3.4.0.2                   <pip>
bcolz                     0.8.1                np19py27_0  
beautiful-soup            4.3.2                    py27_0  
beautifulsoup4            4.3.2                     <pip>
binstar                   0.10.1                   py27_3  
bitarray                  0.8.1                    py27_0  
blaze                     0.7.2                np19py27_0  
blaze-core                0.7.3                np19py27_0  
blz                       0.6.2                np19py27_0  
bokeh                     0.8.1                np19py27_1  
boto                      2.36.0                   py27_0  
cairo                     1.12.18                       1  
casuarius                 1.1                      py27_0  
cdecimal                  2.3                      py27_0  
certifi                   14.05.14                 py27_0  
cffi                      0.9.2                    py27_0  
chaco                     4.4.1                np19py27_0  
clyent                    0.3.4                    py27_0  
colorama                  0.3.3                    py27_0  
conda                     3.13.0                   py27_0  
conda-build               1.10.2                   py27_0  
conda-env                 2.1.4                    py27_0  
configobj                 5.0.6                    py27_0  
cryptography              0.8                      py27_0  
curl                      7.38.0                        0  
cx-freeze                 4.3.4                     <pip>
cython                    0.22                     py27_0  
cytoolz                   0.7.2                    py27_0  
datashape                 0.4.4                np19py27_1  
dateutil                  2.1                      py27_2  
decorator                 3.4.0                    py27_0  
docutils                  0.12                     py27_0  
dynd-python               0.6.5                np19py27_0  
enable                    4.3.0                np19py27_3  
enaml                     0.9.8                    py27_0  
enum34                    1.0.4                    py27_0  
fastcache                 1.0.2                    py27_0  
flask                     0.10.1                   py27_1  
fontconfig                2.11.1                        2  
freetype                  2.5.2                         0  
funcsigs                  0.4                      py27_0  
future                    0.14.3                   py27_0  
futures                   2.2.0                    py27_0  
genesis-pyapi             1.1.2                     <pip>
gevent                    1.0.1                    py27_0  
gevent-websocket          0.9.3                    py27_0  
greenlet                  0.4.5                    py27_0  
grin                      1.2.1                    py27_1  
h5py                      2.4.0                np19py27_0  
hdf5                      1.8.14                        0  
into                      0.2.2                np19py27_0  
ipython                   3.0.0                    py27_0  
ipython-notebook          3.0.0                    py27_1  
ipython-qtconsole         3.0.0                    py27_0  
itsdangerous              0.24                     py27_0  
jdcal                     1.0                      py27_0  
jedi                      0.8.1                    py27_0  
jinja2                    2.7.3                    py27_1  
jpeg                      8d                            0  
jsonschema                2.4.0                    py27_0  
kiwisolver                0.1.3                    py27_0  
lcms                      1.19                          0  
libdynd                   0.6.5                         0  
libffi                    3.0.13                        0  
libpng                    1.5.13                        1  
libsodium                 0.4.5                         0  
libtiff                   4.0.2                         1  
libxml2                   2.9.0                         0  
libxslt                   1.1.28                        0  
llvm                      3.3                           0  
llvmlite                  0.2.2                    py27_1  
llvmpy                    0.12.7                   py27_0  
lxml                      3.4.2                    py27_0  
markupsafe                0.23                     py27_0  
matplotlib                1.4.3                np19py27_1  
mistune                   0.5.1                    py27_0  
mock                      1.0.1                    py27_0  
mpi4py                    1.3                      py27_0  
mpich2                    1.4.1p1                       0  
multipledispatch          0.4.7                    py27_0  
networkx                  1.9.1                    py27_0  
nltk                      3.0.2                np19py27_0  
nose                      1.3.4                    py27_1  
numba                     0.17.0               np19py27_0  
numexpr                   2.3.1                np19py27_0  
numpy                     1.9.2                    py27_0  
odo                       0.3.1                np19py27_0  
openpyxl                  1.8.5                    py27_0  
openssl                   1.0.1k                        1  
orange                    2.7.8                     <pip>
pandas                    0.15.2               np19py27_1  
patchelf                  0.6                           0  
pathlib                   1.0.1                     <pip>
patsy                     0.3.0                np19py27_0  
pep8                      1.6.2                    py27_0  
pil                       1.1.7                    py27_1  
pillow                    2.7.0                    py27_1  
pip                       7.0.3                    py27_0  
pixman                    0.26.2                        0  
ply                       3.4                      py27_0  
progressbar               2.3                      py27_0  
psutil                    2.2.1                    py27_0  
ptyprocess                0.4                      py27_0  
py                        1.4.26                   py27_0  
py2cairo                  1.10.0                   py27_2  
pyasn1                    0.1.7                    py27_0  
pycosat                   0.6.1                    py27_0  
pycparser                 2.10                     py27_0  
pycrypto                  2.6.1                    py27_0  
pycurl                    7.19.5.1                 py27_0  
pyface                    4.4.0                    py27_0  
pyflakes                  0.8.1                    py27_0  
pygments                  2.0.2                    py27_0  
pylibftdi                 0.14.1                   py27_0  
pymba                     0.1                       <pip>
pymongo                   2.8                      py27_0  
pyopenssl                 0.14                     py27_0  
pyparsing                 2.0.3                    py27_0  
pyqt                      4.11.3                   py27_0  
pyserial                  2.7                      py27_0  
pytables                  3.1.1                np19py27_2  
pytest                    2.6.4                    py27_0  
python                    2.7.10                        0  
python-dateutil           2.4.1                    py27_0  
pytz                      2015.2                   py27_0  
pyyaml                    3.11                     py27_0  
pyzmq                     14.5.0                   py27_0  
qt                        4.8.6                         0  
readline                  6.2                           2  
redis                     2.6.9                         0  
redis-py                  2.10.3                   py27_0  
requests                  2.7.0                    py27_0  
rope                      0.9.4                    py27_1  
runipy                    0.1.3                    py27_0  
scikit-image              0.11.2               np19py27_0  
scikit-learn              0.15.2               np19py27_0  
scipy                     0.15.1               np19py27_0  
setuptools                17.0                     py27_0  
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                   <pip>
sip                       4.16.5                   py27_0  
six                       1.9.0                    py27_0  
slumber                   0.7.1                     <pip>
sockjs-tornado            1.0.1                    py27_0  
sphinx                    1.2.3                    py27_0  
spyder                    2.3.4                    py27_1  
spyder-app                2.3.4                    py27_0  
sqlalchemy                0.9.9                    py27_0  
sqlite                    3.8.4.1                       1  
ssl_match_hostname        3.4.0.2                  py27_0  
statsmodels               0.6.1                np19py27_0  
sympy                     0.7.6                    py27_0  
system                    5.8                           2  
tables                    3.1.1                     <pip>
terminado                 0.5                      py27_0  
theano                    0.6.0                np19py27_0  
thefuck                   1.35                      <pip>
tk                        8.5.18                        0  
toolz                     0.7.1                    py27_0  
tornado                   4.1                      py27_0  
traits                    4.4.0                    py27_0  
traitsui                  4.4.0                    py27_0  
ujson                     1.33                     py27_0  
unicodecsv                0.9.4                    py27_0  
util-linux                2.21                          0  
werkzeug                  0.10.1                   py27_0  
xlrd                      0.9.3                    py27_0  
xlsxwriter                0.6.7                    py27_0  
xlwt                      0.7.5                    py27_0  
yaml                      0.1.4                         0  
zeromq                    4.0.4                         0  
zlib                      1.2.8                         0
```

Am I missing any essential requirements that will prevent these visualize tools package from building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install also [PyQwt5](http://pyqwt.sourceforge.net/) and [PyQtGraph](http://pyqtgraph.org/).

Comment: Thank you very much. It works after PyQwt5 is installed.

Comment: Sure. Didn't know I have to check the button.