# Missing visualizers in default Orange-app on Mac OS X / Anaconda install

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, anaconda, orange

I recently began playing with the Orange visualization environment as supplied via the Anaconda dist.

When trying to run the tutorials from the Functional Genomics workshop, I can't get anything to 'open' other than the initial data-loading. When I try to load the classification tutorial, I get a dialog titled **Error occurred while loading scheme** with the content:

`UnknownWidgetDefinition('Orange.OrangeWidgets.Visualize.OWScatterPlot.OWScatterPlot',)`

Indeed, looking at `visualize` tab in the browser only shows `Venn, Sieve, Mosaic & Stats` tools.

I did a complete clean install of Anaconda, just to see if it was something I had corrupted. No dice.

There is also this, [Most Visualization Tools are Missing from Orange.Canvas (2015/06/15 source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848760/most-visualization-tools-are-missing-from-orange-canvas-2015-06-15-source) but this doesn't seem to be involved in the Mac OS version (e.g., I installed these, `pyqtgraph` from the `conda` universe and `pyqwt5` using another build that someone put on `anaconda`. Still doesn't work.)

Thoughts?

Comment: And, does that solution, i.e. installing PyQwt5 and PyQtGraph packages, work?

Comment: Installed `qwt5` from `anaconda`, (not available in the central `conda` world) and `pyqtgraph` from `conda`, no dice.

Comment: I guess you should submit them a bug report: https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues

Comment: Shall do- thanks. Was sort of hoping that the ol' 'anaconda' tag would get some notice by Continuum :)